# How do I open a directory under the cursor in vim? A gf-like for directories

Tags: vim

For instance, if I had something like:

```
path = '/mnt/data/files/'
```

and my cursor was over `'/mnt/data/files/'`, I'd hit a `gf`-like command and it would open vim `:Explorer` in that folder.

I've searched through StackOverflow, but I only found answers on how to open the directory of the current open file.

Comment: On which OS are you running vim ?

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: then why dont you just try `nautilus <path> --browser` ?

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear in my question. I would like to open an `:Explorer`, within vim, then I'd be able to browse the folder without exiting it.

Comment: "I've searched through StackOverflow" Why do you search on SO in the first place? Use Vim's documentation.

Comment: I've googled it and looked into :Ex doc. This was just to make clear that I didn't find a duplicate on StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't google either. All you need is in the documentation.

Comment: Interesting... I quickly tried and for me, `gf` opens directories also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pressing `<C-r><C-f>` in the command-line inserts the path under the cursor. This means that you can do the following to achieve your goal:

```
:Ex <C-r><C-f><CR>
```

From there, you could simply create a custom mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :Explore <C-r><C-f><CR>
```

Comment: Or maybe `:Ex <cfile>`

Comment: @JairLopez, yes that would work too. But `gf` already does what the OP wants anyway…

Comment: I have dir structures, quite a lot of them, with `@` in them. The above works for dir structures without `@`. When `@` is present though everything before and including the `@` is stripped off. What to do for these dir structures so `@` and before `@` part can be included? ps also `gf` does not work when `@` is present.

Comment: @kes, maybe see `:help isfname` or ask a separate question with some actual example.

Comment: @romainl this is the dir `/home/user/kes@web_address.com/144_p/data-dir-2/data_structure_here`. I had a look at `:help isfname` but so far tried `ex "@"` which opens `ex` on `/home/user/kes` ie everything before the `@` only. Wandering if I can I make `gf` work on a dir structure where an `@` is present as that is the easiest solution.

Comment: Let's see that in a separate question.

Comment: `:nnoremap gO :!xdg-open <cfile><CR>` this is opening dir's without `@` but not with `@` in the path. In that sense same problem as before, though more utility. Does anyone know how `<cfile>` can be made to accomodate spaces and unusual characters? `:help <cfile>` does not say much. Quotes around `<cfile>`, like this `"<cfile>"` don't help.

Comment: @romainl that is incomprehensible. You will need to explain.